# Android listview: there is a header of listview, how can I add a click event to a textview element?

Tags: android, android-listview, click

In a fragment,there is a listview, and I add a header to listview.

There is MainActivity.java,I add a click event. MyAdapter is a class that I defined.

```
MyAdapter adapter;
ListView search_history_list;
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();


LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_listview_header, null);
search_history_list.addHeaderView(header,null,false);
View listheader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_listview_header,null);
TextView clearAll = (TextView)listheader.findViewById(R.id.clearall);
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),list);
search_history_list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_history_list);
search_history_list.setAdapter(adapter);
clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list.removeAll(list);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                search_history_list.invalidate();
            }
        });
clearAll.setEnabled(true);
```

search_listview_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="热门搜索"
        android:textSize="15sp"

        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>

    <com.shijiebang.offlinemap.commom.view.FlowLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_flowLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp">

    </com.shijiebang.offlinemap.commom.view.FlowLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="搜索历史"
            android:textSize="15sp"

            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clearall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="清除搜索历史"
            android:textColor="#49A2FC"
            android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i click the textview, it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the `header` as list view header. 
But find view and set onclick in a another instance of view `listheader` 
So your setonclick code will not work.
Try this: `View listheader = header;`
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code, I cannot see where the view "listheader" is used. So I'm not sure how the text view can be clicked. I would suggest that create a model and a layout for your list item (i.e., each row of the list) then instantiate each row in your customised adapter and set the click listener. To improve the performance of your list, you can implement a view holder. Check this out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder